# How to extend partition in CentOS 8

Tags: centos, centos8, fdisk

I hope someone can help me here. I have below partition in my CentOS 8 which is a VM hosted in hyper-v 2012.

```
[root@appliance ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G  8.5M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       4.0G  997M  3.1G  25% /
/dev/sda1       488M   80M  373M  18% /boot
/dev/sda3      1014M   40M  975M   4% /tmp
/dev/sda5       4.5G  4.5G   20K 100% /var/lib/mysql
tmpfs           787M     0  787M   0% /run/user/0
```

MYSQL has stopped due to disk being 100% full. I have added more storage to the virtual disk through hyper-v. Have extended it to 30GB.

```
[root@appliance ~]# parted -l /dev/sda
Model: Msft Virtual Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 32.2GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   primary   ext4         boot
 2      538MB   4833MB  4295MB  primary   xfs
 3      4833MB  5907MB  1074MB  primary   xfs
 4      5907MB  10.7GB  4831MB  extended
 5      5908MB  10.7GB  4830MB  logical   xfs
```

However I'm not too sure how to extend MYSQL partition to give to give additional space which I have added to the disk. I have tried following few articles online, but I have not had any success so far. Greatly appreciate if someone can help me out here.

fdisk-l output also below.

```
[root@appliance ~]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 30 GiB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf8386911

Device     Boot    Start      End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048  1050623 1048576  512M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        1050624  9439231 8388608    4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3        9439232 11536383 2097152    1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       11536384 20971519 9435136  4.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       11538432 20971519 9433088  4.5G 83 Linux
```

Thank you.

Comment: First make a backup. Then increase the extended partition sda4 first, once that is done you can increase the logical partition sda5 and extend the file system there.

Comment: And if you ever find the person who made this bizarre partitioning scheme, ask them what they were thinking.

Comment: @hermanb is below what I need to do? 

`- start fdisk /dev/sda
u (don't mind the depricated warning)
n
p
(leave all the questions to default answer)
w
REBOOT
pvcreate /dev/sda4
vgextend zabbix-vg /dev/sda4
lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/sda5
resize2fs /dev/sda5
`

Comment: @MichaelHampton this is the zabbix appliance, not sure why the partition was done in such a way :(.

Comment: I have been trying to follow this guide mainly but no luck :( https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-help/46027-increasing-available-diskspace-zabbix-3-0-appliance-in-hyper-v-2008

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost take a backup, or snapshot, the vm before making any changes as any partition modifications always have a chance of doing bad things to the disk.

What you're looking for is `growpart`.
`growpart /dev/sda 4` to fill the remainder of the disk and then increase the size of sda5 by the same command (`growpart /dev/sda 5`) if you want it to fill all of sda4.

If you only want it to fill a portion of `sda4` then use `parted resizepart number end`.  Number is partition number and end is final, larger, partition size.

Once you have sda5's partition expanded, you'll want to increase the filesystem size with `xfs_growfs /var/lib/mysql`